# Function called 2 times, I expected one time

Tags: angularjs, function

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var app = angular.module( "test", [] );  

        app.run(function () {
            angular.element.prototype.has = function(selector) {
                if ( ! this.length || typeof this === 'undefined' ) return false;
                console.log ( selector );

            };
        });

        app.directive('cacat', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    var g = element[0].querySelector('span');
                    if ( angular.element(g).length ) {
                        element.has(element.has(g) );
                    }
                }
            };
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="test">
        <cacat>
            <span>da</span>
        </cacat>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Why the .has is called 2 times? And first time I get a good element, second time I get an undefined element, and it pass over condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `element.has(element.has(g) );`

here are your two calls. I'm not sure what you expected but both calls return `undefined` because they pass the `! this.length || typeof this === 'undefined'` test (where`this` refers to your `cacat` element, which has a non-zero length), and there is no return beyond that point, thus an implicit `undefined` return value.

Comment: I don't think the second statement is correct, it's not returning `false` as defined. The `console.log` will run because of `! this.length`

Comment: I AM SO inadvertently

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the method twice:

```
element.has(element.has(g));
```

Since `.has()` does not return a value when called with a valid element, you get `undefined` in the second call.